# drop down menu not work after including in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header with dropdown menu on my home page but if i put the header div into another html file and after that if i include it in my home page using jquery load function than the drop-down menu is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="myid">

        </div>
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#myid").load("header.html"); 
    });
    </script> 


    <script src="js/cbpHorizontalMenu.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(function() {
                cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
                cbpHorizontalMenu1.init();
            });
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

*****The header content*****

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="layout">
                <div class="top-header">

                        <div class="top-right">                         
                            <div class="nav-toggler">
                                <button class="toggle-link hidden-bar-opener" data-pixel=".top-menu">Top Menu</button>
                            </div>  

                            <div class="layout">                            
                            <div class="top-menu cbp-hrmenu1">                          
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Our Services</a>
                                        <div class="service-drop cbp-hrsub">
                                            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">                                               
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#">football</a></li>   
                                                        <li><a href="#">cricket</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">hockey</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                            </div>                              
                                        </div>                              
                                    </li>                               



                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Contact Us</a>                                 
                                        <div class="service-drop cbp-hrsub">
                                            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">   
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> +91-99863355333</a></li>  
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i> +91-124382428</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i> skype</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true">mail me </i></a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>          

            </div>          

            <div class="main-menu">
                <div class="layout">

                <div class="nav-toggler">
                       <button class="toggle-link hidden-bar-opener" data-pixel=".main-menu1"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                </div>
                <nav class="main-menu1 cbp-hrmenu">
                    <ul>



                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Category one</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                                    <div>

                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">test </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test </a></li>

                                            <li><a href="#">test </a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>


                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>

                         <li>
                            <a href="#">Category two</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                                    <div>

                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>

                                            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>


                                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>




                    </ul>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

</header>
```

if i copy the content of header in the div than it is working fine. But i want to include it on every page of my site.

Here is the live example http://plnkr.co/edit/51vGFoI7aJF1HUE3Wim9

Comment: fiddle example would be better

Comment: Try to make code proper by adding in fiddle or codepen..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the content is loaded asynchronously, and you try an initialise the menu before it's in the DOM. You need to instead put the initialisation in the callback of `load()`. Try this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpHorizontalMenu.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $("#myid").load("header.html", function() {
                cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
                cbpHorizontalMenu1.init();
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myid"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment . The plunker link was added.

Answer (score 0):

1. if it's in PHP you can name it like header.php

2.then include it `<? include('header.php'); ?>`
put that line of code in the top or where div you want

Comment: no it's not php. the site is on angularJS but here i am using simple Jquery